# SQL Server trigger - connection info

Tags: sql, sql-server, connection-string

is it possible to get MSSQL connection info?
not onli SUSER_ID(), SUSER_NAME(), ORIGINAL_LOGIN(), BUT other like:

- IP
- Connection string
- ect..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get some more information from [sys.dm_exec_connections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181509.aspx):

e.g.

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections 
WHERE session_id = @@SPID
```

This will get the connection info available for the current process (SPID).
This doesn't give the full connection string, but does give some more info like IP address (client_net_address).

This will work for SQL Server 2005 and above.

Comment: that is it
thank you


note:
to take more info like host_name, program_name and other


SELECT 
*
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions ES
JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections CN ON CN.session_id = ES.session_id
WHERE ES.session_id = @@SPID

Answer (score 3):

You didn't mention the version of SQL Server that you're using, but this should work for SQL 2005 and above. You can change the @@SPID as needed.

```
SELECT
    conn.session_ID as SPID,
    conn.client_net_address as IPAddress,
    sess.host_name as MachineName,
    sess.program_name as ApplicationName,
    login_name as LoginName
FROM
    sys.dm_exec_connections conn
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions sess ON
    conn.session_ID = sess.session_ID
WHERE
    conn.session_ID = @@SPID
```